# SQL 2008 developers edition functionality

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to find out if SQL developers edition will support windows 2008 HA / clustering.  According to this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.105).ASPX#High_availability it doesn't support.  Listed in the Express column.

Answer (score 3):

The Developer edition is a specially licensed (can't use it in a production environment) copy of the SQL Server 2008 Enterprise Edition. It costs a negligible amount of money compared to the real Enterprise Edition to download.

The completely free Express edition doesn't have the no-production use limitation but is much more limited in it's database feature set and has a database size restriction.